# Using (char **) vs. (const * char *) vs. (const char **)

Tags: c

I'm trying to wrap my head around the different qualifiers for an array of pointers, or pointer to a pointer. What would be the difference between the following three declarations (the last one of which I think is wrong, but I'm not sure why):

```
char ** strings;

const * char * strings / char * const * strings (?);

const char ** strings;
```

When would one be used over another? And why does the third one (I think?) not make sense at all?

Comment: The second one won't compile.

Comment: Why do *you* think the last one is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` qualifier marks an object as immutable, that is "read-only", but you knew that most probably.

---

```
char ** strings;
```

`strings` is a mutable pointer to a mutable pointer to a mutable character. None of them is `const` obviously.

---

```
const * char * strings;
```

is syntactically wrong.

---

```
char * const * strings;
```

`strings` is a mutable pointer to an immutable pointer to a mutable character.

---

```
const char ** strings;
```

`strings` is a mutable pointer to a mutable pointer to an immutable character.

This makes sense if you need such a variable.